# how to convert pipe delimited string into list python for column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, list

I need to convert csv file to json. In csv file email is delimited by pipe(|) in a string. Need to convert into list. I am able to convert into list but only 1 email is coming in output.

**Input Data in csf format**

```
first_name, last_name, email
"ABC","DEF","abc@gmail.com|def@gmail.com"
"CBA","FED","cba@gmail.com|fed@gmail.com"
```

**Expected Ouput Data in json format**

```
[
    {
        "first_name" : "ABC",
        "last_name" : "DEF",
        "email" : ["abc@gmail","def@gmail"]
    }
    {
        "first_name" : "CBA",
        "last_name" : "DEF",
        "email" : ["abc@gmail","def@gmail"]
    }
]
```

**Getting output**

```
[
    {
        "first_name" : "ABC",
        "last_name" : "DEF",
        "email" : ["abc@gmail"]
    }
    {
        "first_name" : "CBA",
        "last_name" : "DEF",
        "email" : ["abc@gmail"]
    }
]
```

**code tried**

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename")
df.Email = df.Email.str.split('|')
df1 = df.to_json("filename", orient='records')
```

Comment: I tried it with pandas v1.0.5 and your code works as expected. Are you sure you have included all relevant code? Did you check your data?

Comment: df.to_json() need to write the final data frame to json file .

Comment: if you have some other way let me know

Comment: Did you resolve your error?

Comment: It works the same code for me. just changed the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using pandas v1.0.5 and it works as expected.

[image]

In your example of csv data the first line has spaces after the comma, but that would just throw an error, when trying to access `df.email`.

**Conclusion:** The error must be somewhere else. Either you didn't share all relevant code with us, the data is actually different, or it actually does the job correctly and there is no error, but it's just how the data is.